# Multiple linked pointers

Tags: c, pointers

For a homework I have to build the following simple scenario.

[image]

My attempt looks like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  char* heap1P = malloc(sizeof(char**));
  char* heap2P = malloc(sizeof(char*));
  char* heap3P = malloc(sizeof(char));

  *heap3P = 'X';
  *heap2P = heap3P;
  *heap1P = heap2P;

  char*** stackP = heap1P;

  puts("stack                           | heap ");
  printf("%p [%p] | %p [%p] => %p [%p] => %c [%p] \n", stackP, &stackP, *heap1P, heap1P, *heap2P, heap2P, *heap3P, heap3P);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

First I allocate space in memory and after that I set the values.
The output is like (format: value [address]):

```
stack                           | heap 
0x55a1e184f260 [0x7fff05e55c08] | 0xffffff80 [0x55a1e184f260] => 0xffffffa0 [0x55a1e184f280] => X [0x55a1e184f2a0]
```

As you can see the stack value contains the address of the first heap value. But the heap values are not correct. They do not contain the address of the following heap value.

Why the heap values do not contain the given addresses?

Comment: You've declared all your multiple indirection pointers as single indirection pointers.

Comment: There is nothing stating that 2 consecutive mallocs lie close to eachother. It can allocate memory basically anywhere. You just have to make sure that one heap-node points to the next one. Also I do not think your implementation, using stuff lite char ***, is correct either

Comment: `char*** stackP = heap1P;` isn't even valid C. Most of this code won't compile cleanly.

Comment: At least formally there is no question here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is only that you have declared the various pointer as `char *`. It may look unimportant, because in common implementations all pointers have same representation. But it becomes essential as soon as you dereference them!

Let us look at the following statements:

```
*heap3P = 'X';
*heap2P = heap3P;
```

First one is correct: `heap3P` is a `char *` and `*heap3P` is assigned a `char`, all is fine here.

Second one is terrible. As `heap2P` is a `char *`, `heap3P` if converted to an integer and trimmed into a `char`! Long story short: you only store one byte from the pointer... And if you look carefully to the values, you will see that the different `heapx` are indeed single byte values...

The fix is trivial:

```
char*** heap1P = malloc(sizeof(char**));
char** heap2P = malloc(sizeof(char*));
char* heap3P = malloc(sizeof(char));
```

and the code compiles without a warning and runs as expected!

Comment: I'd drop this `***`-comment. In the context of the question it does not add value to the answer  and as well can very well be taken a your personal opinion. If left in, it made sense to elaborate more on what the "*specific use cases*" were and with  doing so diverting away from the question even more.

Comment: @alk: you are probably right. I wrote it because I have never seen a real world use case for `***` but I agree that it is irrelevant for the question. I have removed it from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want something like:

```
typedef struct heap {
    char val;
    struct heap *next;
} heap_t;

int main()
{
    // allocate first
    heap_t *head = malloc(sizeof(heap_t));
    head->val = 'A';
    // allocate second node
    head->next = malloc(sizeof(heap_t));
    head->next->val = 'B';

    head->next->next = malloc(sizeof(heap_t));
    head->next->next->val = 'X';

    heap_t *tmp = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++, tmp = tmp->next) {
        printf("[%p, %c]\n", tmp, tmp->val);
    }
}
```

Note that this is a quick draft, and you should of course do the creation of new nodes inside a function, not the manual way I did here. Do not forget to free the memory afterwards.

Comment: "*you would want something like*" Why?

Comment: I wrote "I *think* you would want ..". I assumed that this was what OP was looking for. An easy, general way of implementing a list.